# Dropdown list with as inner join request

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know why when I want to change in my form an item from my dropdown list ; the list begins always on the first element (from my DB) and never on the element that I had chosen previously?

I think my problem is here:

```
    <tr> 
        <td>Nom du Club:</td>
            <td><select name="fk_club">
                <option>Choisissez un club</option>
        <?php 

                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($reso)) 
                    { 
                ?>  

                <option value="<?php echo $data['pk_club']?>"><?php echo $data['nom_club']?></option>

                <?php }

                ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
```

I give you my code because I don't understand my problems.

```
<?php
// including the database connection file
include_once("config_bd.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   

    $pk_membre = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pk_membre']);

    $nom_membre = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nom_membre']);
    $prenom_membre = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['prenom_membre']);
    $dateNaissance_membre  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['dateNaissance_membre']);
    $fk_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['fk_club']);   


    if(empty($nom_membre) || empty($prenom_membre) || empty($dateNaissance_membre) || empty($fk_club)){ 

        if(empty($nom_membre)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le nom du membre est vide.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($prenom_membre)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le prenom du membre est vide.</font><br/>";
        }   

        if(empty($dateNaissance_membre)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>La date de naissance du membre est vide.</font><br/>";
        }   

        if(empty($fk_club)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le fk club est vide.</font><br/>";
        }

    } else {    
        //updating the table
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE membres SET nom_membre='$nom_membre',prenom_membre='$prenom_membre', dateNaissance_membre='$dateNaissance_membre', fk_club='$fk_club' WHERE pk_membre=$pk_membre");

        //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: vue_membre.php");
    }
}


//getting id from url
$pk_membre = $_GET['pk_membre'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM membres WHERE pk_membre=$pk_membre");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nom_membre = $res['nom_membre'];
    $prenom_membre = $res['prenom_membre'];
    $dateNaissance_membre = $res['dateNaissance_membre'];
    $fk_club = $res['fk_club'];
}

// requete pour la liste déroulante
$reso = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT pk_club,nom_club FROM clubs"); 

?>
<html>
<head>  

</head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Palais des Sports</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css">
<body>  

    <div class="bandeau-bleu">
    <h2>Palais des Sports</h2>
    <a href="index.php?logout='1'"><i class="material-icons">&#xe897;</i></a>
    <a href="welcome.php"><i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="form_encodage">
        <a href="vue_membre.php"><h3>Cliquez ici pour afficher les enregistrements</h3></a>
    <br />
        <h4> Editer un enregistrement</h4><br />

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit_membre.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Nom du Membre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nom_membre" value="<?php echo $nom_membre;?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>Prenom du Membre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="prenom_membre" value="<?php echo $prenom_membre;?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>Date Naissance du Membre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dateNaissance_membre" value="<?php echo $dateNaissance_membre;?>"></td>

            <tr> 
                <td>Nom du Club:</td>
                    <td><select name="fk_club">
                        <option>Choisissez un club</option>
                <?php 

                        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($reso)) 
                            { 
                        ?>  

                        <option value="<?php echo $data['pk_club']?>"><?php echo $data['nom_club']?></option>

                        <?php }

                        ?>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>

        </td></tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="bouton_bleu" value="Update"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="pk_membre" value=<?php echo $_GET['pk_membre'];?>></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: When you want it to start on a certain element you need to add SELECTED to the `<option>` area on the element you want it to start on.

Comment: Really try to provide a [minimal working code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this will make it easier for others to spot your exact problem and will teach you to track down problems.